# Make 3 columns 75% width and center aligned in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootply snippet: https://www.bootply.com/FHwoiollCJ

As you can see, I have an element that is 75% of the width.

I'd like to center align the 3 items underneath this box so that the 1st and 3rd boxes don't overhang. How do I do this?

```
<header class="masthead text-white">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-9 mx-auto" style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);">
        <h1 class="mb-5">H1</h1>
        <p>We pride ourselves...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 mx-auto">
          <div class="" style="background:red">
            <h3>TEST</h3>
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 mx-auto">
        <div class="features-icons-item mx-auto mb-5 mb-lg-0 mb-lg-3" style="background:red">
          <h3>TEST</h3>
          <p>test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 mx-auto">
        <div class="features-icons-item mx-auto mb-0 mb-lg-3" style="background:red">
            <h3>TEST</h3>
            <p>test</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested grid solution: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class="masthead text-white">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-9 mx-auto" >
            <div class="p-3" style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);">
              <h1 class="mb-5">H1</h1>
              <p>We pride ourselves...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-9 mx-auto">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="" style="background:red">
                    <h3>TEST</h3>
                    <p>test</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="features-icons-item mx-auto mb-5 mb-lg-0 mb-lg-3" style="background:red">
                  <h3>TEST</h3>
                  <p>test</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="features-icons-item mx-auto mb-0 mb-lg-3" style="background:red">
                    <h3>TEST</h3>
                    <p>test</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: Amazing, @ReSedano - thank you so much. Must research nesting further.

Comment: You're welcome...but it is Bootstrap amazing, not me. ;-)

Comment: You're still a great help : )

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
    <div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9 mx-auto" style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);">
      <h1 class="mb-5">H1</h1>
      <p>We pride ourselves...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9 mx-auto" style="padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 mx-auto">
        <div class="" style="background:red">
          <h3>TEST</h3>
          <p>test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 mx-auto">
        <div class="features-icons-item mx-auto mb-5 mb-lg-0 mb-lg-3" style="background:red">
          <h3>TEST</h3>
          <p>test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 mx-auto">
        <div class="features-icons-item mx-auto mb-0 mb-lg-3" style="background:red">
          <h3>TEST</h3>
          <p>test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to a [bootply snippet](https://www.bootply.com/UHpThtAfXX).

I think your issue is with the padding added by bootstrap layout classes. I've just juggled a few of your divs so that they are nested in an equal number of bootstrap classes (i.e. `.col-lg-9`). This has lined things up nicely.

I also had to add `margin-bottom: 0px;` to the paragraph in your wide red div so that the three grey divs below weren't pushed down. Add introduced a new class `padding-10` so that it looks similar to the original.

Play around with the styling and I think this will do what you want, if not let me know.

```
<header class="masthead text-white">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row col-lg-9 mx-auto">
      <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto">
        <div style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);">
          <h1 class="mb-5">H1</h1>
          <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">We pride ourselves...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-lg-9 mx-auto">
      <div class="col-lg-4 mx-auto">
          <div class="" style="background:red">
            <h3>TEST</h3>
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 mx-auto">
        <div class="features-icons-item mx-auto mb-5 mb-lg-0 mb-lg-3" style="background:red">
          <h3>TEST</h3>
          <p>test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 mx-auto">
        <div class="features-icons-item mx-auto mb-0 mb-lg-3" style="background:red">
            <h3>TEST</h3>
            <p>test</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```